# Read specific information from nested json in python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have a nested json file which I read with python. I am interested only in specfic information. Suppose I have following json file

```
  {
    "metadata_id": "3596fe93-5e4d-4ba9-8b10-c7ce28b18475",
    "kistler": {
      "metadata_id": "c2faa0df-e07a-40bb-91db-ac95281e0bfb",
      "actualValues": {
        "Zykluszaehler": {
          "name": "Zykluszaehler",
          "unit": "-",
          "value": 196.0,
          "type": 2
        },
        "Zykluszeit": {
          "name": "Zykluszeit",
          "unit": "s",
          "value": 5082.0,
          "type": 2
        },
        "Parameter 1": {
          "name": "Parameter 1",
          "unit": "s",
          "value": 0.0,
          "type": 1
        },
        "Parameter 2": {
          "name": "Parameter 2",
          "unit": "Schalter",
          "value": 0.0,
          "type": 1
        }
      },
      "mdeValues": {
        "Status": "0",
        "Vollautomatik": "1",
        "Manuell": "0",
        "Maschinenstatus": "4",
        "Maschinenstillstand": "0",
        "ManuelleBuchung": "",
        "ManuellerStatus": "0GM",
        "Alarme": "",
        "Auftrag": "NONE",
        "Artikel": "NONE",
        "Werkzeug": "NONE",
        "Charge": "NONE",
        "Zykluszaehler": "196",
        "Anfahrausschuss": "",
        "Aussschusszaehler": "-1",
        "GutteileZaehler": "-1",
        "Kavitaeten": "1",
        "Sollstueck": "0",
        "GutZaehler": "10325",
        "BruttoZaehler": "10325",
        "SchlechtZaehler": "0",
        "AusschussGrund": "",
        "AusschussAnzahl": "",
        "Bemerkung": "",
        "Message": "",
        "SollZykluszeit": "180",
        "SollStkProStd": "",
        "QS_TPP_ID": "200",
        "Folgeauftrag": "",
        "SollAusschuss": "0",
        "SchusszahlProduktion": "3",
        "PdeCommand": "",
        "ExternalStrValues": "",
        "ExternalValues": "",
        "ULDL": "00",
        "Personal": "NONE",
        "SummeIstLaufzeitAuftrag": "644713",
        "SummeSollLaufzeitAuftrag": "26029726",
        "SummeIstLaufzeit": "644713",
        "SummeSollLaufzeit": "22286461",
        "Freizeit": "0",
        "SummeAusschuss": "0",
        "StartIstMenge": "0",
        "StartSchlechtMenge": "0",
        "StartSummeAusschuss": "0",
        "OrderId": "",
        "Option1": "",
        "Option2": "",
        "Rohstoff": "",
        "SchichtID": "Spätschicht",
        "Startzeit": "2019-05-08 14:00:00",
        "Endzeit": "2019-05-08 22:00:00",
        "SollLaufzeit": "28800",
        "Barcode": "NONE",
        "ProgStillstand": "0",
        "SummeLaufzeit": "26029726",
        "ExternalCommand": "zyklusoutofrange=1"
      },
      "processDataCreatedUtc": "2019-05-08T14:54:07.4391900Z",
      "processDataCreatedLocal": "2019-05-08T16:54:07.4391900+02:00",
      "cycle": 196,
      "machineId": "T_68539",
      "pdeMachineId": 102,
      "dmc": "0020000000NONE20190508145407000000242T_68539000NONE"
    },
    "id": { "dmc": "0020000000NONE20190508145407000000242T_68539000NONE" },
    "MAi": {
      "metadata_id": "2c8b4fd6-7142-4e1d-83af-199ba6967cde",
      "samples": [
        {
          "metadata_id": "ad123bdd-1d1d-49b8-84d6-6308eab38744",
          "sampleID": 74517,
          "parameterID": 9,
          "equipmentID": 1,
          "SampleDateTimestamp": 1557327571,
          "parameterName": "Produktcode",
          "Unit": "Status1",
          "UTCBias": -120,
          "dataKeys": [
            {
              "metadata_id": "120c99f7-c768-4605-9874-75be45d0a0fc",
              "name": "Bauteil",
              "description": "",
              "ID": 2,
              "LDDID": 1,
              "value": "1",
              "groupID": 1,
              "dkType": 0
            },
            {
              "metadata_id": "9a5a52a5-1e1e-4d99-a9f9-728e33cad934",
              "name": "Produktcode",
              "description": "",
              "ID": 1,
              "LDDID": 1,
              "value": "0020000000NONE20190508145407000000242T_68539000NONE",
              "groupID": 2,
              "dkType": 0
            }
          ],
          "rawValues": [
            {
              "metadata_id": "ac178e72-86a0-4dc6-8b5f-10129cce4156",
              "value": 1.0,
              "dataKeys": []
            }
          ],
          "SMAX": 0.0,
          "SMEAN": 0.0,
          "SMEDIAN": 0.0,
          "SMIN": 0.0,
          "SN": 0,
          "SSD": 0.0
        }
      ]
    },
    "processDataCreatedUtc": "2019-05-08T14:54:07.4400000",
    "processDataCreatedLocal": "2019-05-08T16:54:07.4400000"
  }
```

I would like to have a pandas frame with the following structure:

```
Zykluszahler|Zykluszeit|Parameter 1| Parameter 2
   196.0        5082.0     0.0        0.0
```

Up to now I made it until here

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from flatten_json import flatten
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open(r"filepath") as data_file:
data=json.load(data_file)
df=json_normalize(data["kistler"])
```

If I use this lines I get all the information, i.e.

```
'actualValues.Prozessueberwachung_Schalter_SW.name',
   'actualValues.Prozessueberwachung_Schalter_SW.type',
   'actualValues.Prozessueberwachung_Schalter_SW.unit',
   'actualValues.Prozessueberwachung_Schalter_SW.value',
   'actualValues.S11013_Hub_A_Auswerfer_zurueck_verzoegert.name',
   'actualValues.S11013_Hub_A_Auswerfer_zurueck_verzoegert.type',
   'actualValues.S11013_Hub_A_Auswerfer_zurueck_verzoegert.unit',
   'actualValues.S11013_Hub_A_Auswerfer_zurueck_verzoegert.value',
   'actualValues.Zykluszaehler.name', 'actualValues.Zykluszaehler.type',
   'actualValues.Zykluszaehler.unit', 'actualValues.Zykluszaehler.value',
   'actualValues.Zykluszeit.name', 'actualValues.Zykluszeit.type',
   'actualValues.Zykluszeit.unit', 'actualValues.Zykluszeit.value',
   'cycle', 'dmc', 'machineId', 'mdeValues.Alarme',
   'mdeValues.Anfahrausschuss', 'mdeValues.Artikel', 'mdeValues.Auftrag',
   'mdeValues.AusschussAnzahl', 'mdeValues.AusschussGrund',
   'mdeValues.Aussschusszaehler', 'mdeValues.Barcode',
   'mdeValues.Bemerkung', 'mdeValues.BruttoZaehler', 'mdeValues.Charge',
   'mdeValues.Endzeit', 'mdeValues.ExternalCommand',
   'mdeValues.ExternalStrValues', 'mdeValues.ExternalValues',
   'mdeValues.Folgeauftrag', 'mdeValues.Freizeit', 'mdeValues.GutZaehler',
   'mdeValues.GutteileZaehler', 'mdeValues.Kavitaeten',
   'mdeValues.Manuell', 'mdeValues.ManuelleBuchung',
   'mdeValues.ManuellerStatus', 'mdeValues.Maschinenstatus',
   'mdeValues.Maschinenstillstand', 'mdeValues.Message',
   'mdeValues.Option1', 'mdeValues.Option2', 'mdeValues.OrderId',
   'mdeValues.PdeCommand', 'mdeValues.Personal',
   'mdeValues.ProgStillstand', 'mdeValues.QS_TPP_ID', 'mdeValues.Rohstoff',
   'mdeValues.SchichtID', 'mdeValues.SchlechtZaehler',
   'mdeValues.SchusszahlProduktion', 'mdeValues.SollAusschuss',
   'mdeValues.SollLaufzeit', 'mdeValues.SollStkProStd',
   'mdeValues.SollZykluszeit', 'mdeValues.Sollstueck',
   'mdeValues.StartIstMenge', 'mdeValues.StartSchlechtMenge',
   'mdeValues.StartSummeAusschuss', 'mdeValues.Startzeit',
   'mdeValues.Status', 'mdeValues.SummeAusschuss',
   'mdeValues.SummeIstLaufzeit', 'mdeValues.SummeIstLaufzeitAuftrag',
   'mdeValues.SummeLaufzeit', 'mdeValues.SummeSollLaufzeit',
   'mdeValues.SummeSollLaufzeitAuftrag', 'mdeValues.ULDL',
   'mdeValues.Vollautomatik', 'mdeValues.Werkzeug',
   'mdeValues.Zykluszaehler', 'metadata_id', 'pdeMachineId',
   'processDataCreatedLocal', 'processDataCreatedUtc'
```

If I add following to my code

```
df=json_normalize(data["kistler"],"actualValues")
```

I get the names but not the values and columns. I feel I am not that far away. For any kind of help I would be really gratreful

Cheers

Comment: to be specific I would like to have a daframe constructed from the nested dict "actualValues". Again thanks a lot for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just build the data *by hand*:

```
with open(r"filepath") as data_file:
    data=json.load(data_file)["kistler"]["actualValues"]

df = pd.DataFrame({k: [v["value"]] for k,v in data.items()})
```

It should give:

```
   Zykluszaehler  Zykluszeit  Parameter 1  Parameter 2
0          196.0      5082.0          0.0          0.0
```

Comment: wow thank you so much :)
This really helps me.
Another question is: Is this a time efficient process? To have a better overview I deleted many items from the json file. In real life I have to deal with many items which will have many values. So if I use a for loop this might be very time consuming.
If you know a less time consuming approach that would be great :)

Cheers and thank you very much

Comment: IMHO, it should be reasonably efficient. You have to load the json data as a nested Python dictionary. Building a new dictionary by a list comprehension is a standard operation in Python and should be reasonably fast. And building a dataframe form a dict of arrays is fast, because it just build numpy arrays from the Python arrays.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.
I do have one (last) question :)
Suppose there is an additional dict inside the json file which I would like to read, which has the name "setvalues"
How can I also read these data. Just adding ["setvalues"] to data=json.load(..) does not work. What can I do here :)

Comment: the "setvalues" dict has exactly the same structure. What I could do is: Having one dataframe with "actualValues" and one with "setValues" and use pd.concat[frame1,frame2]. However, I think there is a better solution for this